# Extract eye/camera position from a view Matrix

Tags: opengl, c++

I'm trying to improve my Camera. This camera owns a target (vec3 _at), a position (vec3 _eye) and a view mat4. When I move the mouse, I perform a rotation to the view matrix, according to 2 angles (_angleY, _angleZ), so that it gives the feeling the world is turning and not the cam.

Here is what I have, which works :

```
// Called each frame
void Camera::look(bool rotation)
{
    // Computes view Matrix
    _view.lookAt(_eye.X,_eye.Y,_eye.Z,
                 _at.X, _at.Y, _at.Z,
                 0, 0, 1);

    // Apply rotation to the matrix, according to angles
    if(rotation) {
        _view.rotate(_angleY, 0, 1, 0, _at);
        _view.rotate(_angleZ, 0, 0, 1, _at);
    }
}
```

This perfectly works. I'm able to make my world rotating around a selected target (vec3). My problem is that my eye position is not updated each frame since I update my angles which apply a new rotation. Then my eye position is wrong and I need it to be updated each frame for another calculation.

Then, I'm trying to extract the eye position after the rotation, update it, and set angles to 0 (hoping it's the best solution...)

Therefore, I need to extract the eye position of my camera, from my modelview matrix. Here is what I'm trying to do, according to what I read [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22283/how-to-get-translation-from-view-matrix?newreg=4797a1f81db14d96b4e3ea175bb9d01c) , in the last comment :

```
void Camera::look(bool rotation)
{
    // Computes view Matrix
    _view.lookAt(_eye.X,_eye.Y,_eye.Z,
                 _at.X, _at.Y, _at.Z,
                 0, 0, 1);
    if(_angleY != 0 || _angleZ !=0)
    {
        if(rotation) {
            _view.rotate(_angleY, 0, 1, 0, _at);
            _view.rotate(_angleZ, 0, 0, 1, _at);
        }

        Vector3D d;
        d.X = _view[3];
        d.Y = _view[7];
        d.Z = _view[11];
        // This creates a vector by multiplying -d by the mat3 part of the view matrix.
        Vector3D retVec = _view.mul3(-d);
        _eye = retVec;
    }
}
```

few things which might be need :

```
void Matrix4::lookAt(float eyeX, float eyeY, float eyeZ, float targetX, float targetY, float targetZ, float upX, float upY, float upZ)
{
    Vector3D axe (upX, upY, upZ);
    Vector3D forward(targetX - eyeX, targetY - eyeY, targetZ - eyeZ);
    Vector3D normal = Vector3D::crossProduct(forward, axe);   // normal = regard x Axe
    Vector3D newAxe = Vector3D::crossProduct(normal, forward); // newAxe = normal x regard

    // Normalize new vectors
    forward.normalize();
    normal.normalize();
    newAxe.normalize();

    // lookAt matrix
    Matrix4 Matrix4;
    Matrix4.values_[0] = (float)normal[0];
    Matrix4.values_[1] = (float)normal[1];
    Matrix4.values_[2] = (float)normal[2];
    Matrix4.values_[4] = (float)newAxe[0];
    Matrix4.values_[5] = (float)newAxe[1];
    Matrix4.values_[6] = (float)newAxe[2];
    Matrix4.values_[8] = (float)-forward[0];
    Matrix4.values_[9] = (float)-forward[1];
    Matrix4.values_[10] = (float)-forward[2];
    Matrix4.values_[15] = 1.0f;

    *this *= Matrix4;

    // translation is part of the lookAt function
    translate(-eyeX, -eyeY, -eyeZ);
}
```

If someone understands what I'm doing wrong, it might help a lot, I spent a while with this problem...
Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

The lookAt matrix is like this:

```
RightX      RightY      RightZ      0
UpX         UpY         UpZ         0
LookX       LookY       LookZ       0
PosX        PosY        PosZ        1
```

Or in your code

```
normal[0]   normal[1]   normal[2]     0
newAxe[0]   newAxe[1]   newAxe[2]     0
-forward[0] -forward[1] -forward[2]   0
eyeX        eyeY       eyeZ           1
```

With the indexes in the matrix as follows:

```
0           1           2             3
4           5           6             7
8           9           10            11
12          13          14            15
```

As you can see, you should be reading the indexes `12`, `13` and `14`:

```
d.X = _view[12];
d.Y = _view[13];
d.Z = _view[14];
```

---

This is quote from the [OpenGL FAQ on Transformations](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm):

> For programming purposes, OpenGL matrices are 16-value arrays with base vectors laid out contiguously in memory. The translation components occupy the 13th, 14th, and 15th elements of the 16-element matrix, where indices are numbered from 1 to 16 as described in section 2.11.2 of the OpenGL 2.1 Specification.

Of course, we are using 0 based indexes, so the `13th, 14th, and 15th elements` are the indexes `12`, `13` and `14`.

Comment: It seems that I've much more : 
`normal[0]   normal[1]   normal[2]     eyeX`
`newAxe[0]   newAxe[1]   newAxe[2]     eyeY`
`-forward[0] -forward[1] -forward[2]   eyeZ`
 `    0   0      0           1`

Is that possible ? :/
It's actually working well exect for eye position extraction.

Comment: void Matrix4::translate(float X, float Y, float Z)
{
 Matrix4 translation;
 translation.loadIdentity();

 translation.values_[3] = X;
 translation.values_[7] = Y;
 translation.values_[11] = Z;

 *this *= translation;
}

Comment: @QuentinTealrod the four vectors should be oriented in the matrix in the same way. Edit: Based on that I would say that the translation is wrong, I would review the multiplication also.